# Send Axios response as a prop to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am doing a GET request using Axios.  I am able to get the data and log it to the console.  However, when I send the data to my react component, the value does not render.

Here is the GET request:

```
getUserTotalRevenue = (id) => {
    API.getOrderUserTotal(id)
        .then(res => {
            let total = res.data[0].totalAmount.toFixed(2);
            let totalString = total.toString();
            return totalString;
        })
        .catch(error => console.log("User revenue error: " + error))
}
```

Here is where it is being called by the component:

```
<div>
    {this.state.users.map(user => (
        <div key={user._id}>
            <Grid item lg={12}>
                <Card
                    userImage={this.checkUserImage(user)}
                    fullName={this.fullName(user.firstName, user.lastName)}
                    startDate={this.startDate(user.created_at)}                     
                    totalSales={this.getUserTotalRevenue(user._id)}
                />
            </Grid>
        </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this code return method. I hope it will helps you.

```
    <div key={user._id}>
      <Grid item lg={12}>
          <Card
           userImage={this.checkUserImage(user)}
           fullName={this.fullName(user.firstName, user.lastName)}
           startDate={this.startDate(user.created_at)}
           totalSales={this.getUserTotalRevenue(user._id)}

           />
         </Grid>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not be rendering the data since the axios call will be called at the point of rendering the elements. What you can do for this is to get OrderUserTotal data along with the user data (from the same axios call that you got the user data). Or else you can do a lazy loading method where you can have button of some component which will trigger a call to fetch the OrderUserTotal from the Card component.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why nothing is rendered is due to the fact that you are making the call and the data isn't being returned to the component. As mentioned by **@user490889** you should use state to store the value once received and then use the state to render it.